# How can I create a folder in Program Files with UAC on from the command line?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions

Up until now, I've always disabled UAC. Now, I'd like to play by the book and leave it on.

My test case is getting `mkdir c:\program files\foo` to work. When I run it (my user is an admin), I get `Access is denied.`

So, do `runas /user:boom\administrator "mkdir c:\program files\foo"`, hoping this will help. I am prompted for a password. I hit ENTER, and get

> RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - mkdir c:\program files\foo 1327: Logon
>   failure: user account restriction. Possible reasons are blank
>   passwords not allowed, logon hour restrictions, or a policy
>   restriction has been enforced.

Fine, I try to setup a password for the administrator user. I look it up in the users tab in task manager or in User Accounts --> Manage another account, and it's not there.

How should I proceed? Is trying to run mkdir under administrator is even the right track? Should I try to run it under SYSTEM?

As a side note, I also tried installing [Sudo for Windows](http://sudowin.sourceforge.net), but couldn't get it to work, nor could I find a simple "hello world" tutorial for it ([This is the issue I ran into](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudowin/forums/forum/480629/topic/4483026)).

**Update** - OK, I found cmd.exe and right-clicked "run as Administartor", and was then able to change the password by running a privileged taskmgr from it. Still, when I run `runas /user:administrator "mkdir foo"` and type the password I get the same error. This is a brand new laptop, not connected to a domain, and the admin password is not blank.

**Update 2** - This is Win 7 64 bit professional, and I want to do this all from the command line. My goal is to create a simple "sudo.bat" script.

Comment: What edition of Windows 7 is this?

Answer (score 4):

If you logged in account is an "administrator" then you should be able to right-click cmd.exe, "Run AS Administrator", Hit "OK" to UAC, and from there the mkdir should work in Program Files without any further prompting.

If you are not a admin user, and/or open the cmd in the regular user context (not "As Administrator"), then you'll be denied access to Program Files (as you have found).

Are you sure the error you're getting (once you are successfully using a known Administrator account/ password) with RunAs is the SAME error ("1327: Logon failure: user account restriction") and not "2: The system cannot find the file specified."?

Because I get error 2 when I try to RunAs MkDir (as an admin) because Mkdir is NOT an executable file (it's a system command), and that's all RunAs can launch.

You can use CMD.EXE in combination with RunAs, and then feed it the mkdir command.  This is tricky due to nested double quotes, but in the end you should be able to use:

`runas /user:administrator "cmd /C \"mkdir \"c:\\program files\\foo\"\""`

From any command prompt (administrator or not) to pull off what you want.

(The extra backslashes are escape characters)

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure - I'm getting 1327 errors.

Comment: Then you are getting the password wrong, or your (actual) "Administrator" account is disabled.  You should be able to check this via Start->Computer->Right-Click->Manage->Local Users and Group->Users.  This may not work as-is on Home versions of 7, but you have yet to let us know what edition you're using. :)

Comment: The account was disabled, thanks! Now I just have to figure out how to make cmd /c not start in c:\windows\system32. (If I use a relative instead of absolute path as the argument to mkdir, it actually creates c:\windows\system32\foo)

Comment: Side note to his comment:
If you are NOT running as admin but have the admin login you can Ctrl+Shift+right click on the cmd icon and Run as different user and provide credentials for the admin account to gain elevation.

Comment: @ripper234 Yeah, when a CMD is opened as Administrator that's the path they get.  You can use absolute paths as in my example, or perhaps chain a `CD\WantedStartPath && ` Right before the `mkdir`?  Something like `runas /user:administrator "cmd /K \"cd \foo && md bar\""`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to:

- open your Start menu
- type `cmd` in the search, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Accept the UAC prompt (this effectively is the same as running `su`)
- type `mkdir "c:\program files\foo"`

Comment: I want to create a "sudo.bat" script that allows me to do this from the command line.

Comment: Ah, Ok, should have said that sooner :)

Comment: F - What, can't you read my mind from over there? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using PsExec, from sysinternals. Command like:

```
psexec -i -d -s cmd.exe
```

would run command line with System Account privileges.

EDIT: In order for the above command to work, you would need Admin Rights on the target machine(s).  Confirmed that it does work in a domain environment.

Example:  If I had a list of machine names or IP addresses to the machines I wanted to create a directory called "temp1" on the C:\ drive, I would include the list of machine names/IP addresses in a file called " computers.txt ".  Then, from that directory that the text file exists, I would execute the following from a command prompt.

```
psexec -i -d -s @computers.txt cmd /c "mkdir c:\temp1"
```

This will check each computer and then attempt to connect to the computer and then create the directory.

Comment: Would it require a password? If not, then the whole point is moot - I want to be prompted for a password in order to escalate privileges, just like sudo in linux.

Comment: Windows uses current logon credentials and will not prompt as long as you are logged in. There is no elevation password like there is for Linux(users being sodoers). You either have rights to elevate or you don't.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i tried this solution and got the answer. As mentioned in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702762/how-to-create-an-empty-file-at-the-command-line-in-windows) i got this answer.

> copy NUL emptyfile.extension

Try to use this. I also solved the problem

Comment: Are you certain this has to do with the question about creating a folder?

Comment: yes @Facebook. As mentioned in question he wants to create a simple file "sudo.bat", this will work to create the file using cmd